# In what direction do we face to remain at the same height? (directional derivatives and gradients)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We are at a point $(\pi/6, \pi/6)$, on a patch of earth whose height (in cm) is given by

$h(x,y) = \sin(x-2y) + 2\cos(x+3y) + 4$

In what direction should we face to remain at the same height?

My solution:

To stay at the same height, we should travel perpendicular to the gradient vector.

If I'm not mistaken, the gradient vector is $\nabla h(x,y) = (\cos(x-2y) - 2\sin(x+3y), -2\cos(x-2y)-6\sin(x+3y))$

We require the vector normal to this vector, at the point $(\pi/6, \pi/6)$. I know how to quickly ascertain the normal vector, if I am given a vector, say, $(x, 2y, 3z)$. In that case, the normal vector would be $(1, 2, 3)$. However, I'm unsure of how to calculate the normal vector in this scenario. I would appreciate some help. A detailed solution would be nice, where each step is explained with reasoning. This way, I can learn, rather than just being told an answer. Thank you :).

Comment: Yes, that's the formula for the gradient vector, but you only need it at the point $p=(\pi/6,\pi/6)$ so evaluate it there. Then you need to find a direction such that the directional derivative of $h$ at that point is $0$. The directional derivative in the direction given by the vector $v$ is just $(\nabla h)(p) \cdot  v$. You are looking for a $v$ such that $(\nabla h)(p) \cdot  v = 0$.

Comment: @Andrew I actually got to that last stage, but I was unsure of how the algebra is done. If I am not mistaken, we get $\nabla h(\pi/6, \pi/6) = (-\sqrt3/2, -4\sqrt3) \cdot \mathbf c = 0$? How do I do the algebra from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost everything you've said is correct, except the last part about the normal vector. The vector $(x,2y,3z)$ is three-dimensional, so it doesn't *have* a normal vector - there are lots of different directions perpendicular to it. What it looks like you're thinking of is the normal vector to the *plane* $x + 2y + 3z = 0$, which is quite different and not important to this problem.

You want a vector perpendicular to the gradient, which is a *two*-dimensional vector. To find a vector perpendicular to a two-dimensional vector, just reverse the coordinates and slap a negative on one of them - for example, $(-2, 1)$ is perpendicular to $(1,2)$. So evaluate your gradient at that point, and do that.

Comment: A proof for what? The reversal trick? Sure. Two vectors are perpendicular if and only if their dot product is zero. $(a,b) \cdot (b,-a) = ab - ba = 0$.